# xampp and laravel valet conflicting port

Tags: apache, xampp, laravel-valet

Here's my situation:

I've had xampp installed on my mac which already has mysql and apache and it runs all my apps pretty well. It uses port 80 so http://localhost works

Recently, I installed Laravel Valet which used port 80 (conflicting with xampp's apache). Its directory is also different and they'r supposed to serve my laravel apps.

Problem: When valet is running, xampp's apache doesnt start which makes my phpmyadmin not to run as well. But my laravel apps need to use mysql.

Question: I want to keep change valet port to 8000(with *.dev still working) and xampp continues to use port 80 with apache and mysql running.

Comment: You can run laravel apps on xampp as well... Or, you can use a desktop application to manage your mysql instance, then you do not need phpmyadmin.

Comment: Okay, does that mean I wont need valet?

Comment: Do you understand at all what the tools you listed in the question are used for?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the conflicting Port problem you can temporarily stop Valet while you use Xampp and Apache.

Try running `valet stop`

This stops Valet services and prevents the above conflict issues. You can also run `valet start` to start Valet services again.

To see all Valet services run `valet list`